# pip install pyodbc does not install packages only dist info file and vsc does not autocomplete pyodbc code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, pyodbc

I'm using visual studio code version `1.55.2`, virtual environment pip version `21.0.1` and python version `3.8.9`.
When i do `pip install pyodbc` in my `.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages` folder there is only `pyodbc-4.0.30.dist-info` folder. For other packages i have two for example I have `azure_functions-1.7.0.dist-info` and `azure/functions` folder with all packages.

I think because of that vsc does not resolve and autocompletes code from pyodbc library, and I can't go and view sources of pyodbc.

I've found other posts about pip installing only dist info, but in my case it's only for pyodbc. Additionally when i uninstall and install pyodbc it says: `Using cached pyodbc-4.0.30-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (64 kB)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download [the wheel](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/ff/a5cf46041e2a517af80cd446d4689360475764ec35699c75775e5089ad22/pyodbc-4.0.30-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl) and unzip it you can find the main module is `pyodbc.cpython-38-darwin.so`. That's, it's a pure-C Python module. Import is the same, still: `import pyodbc`.

Comment: Ok, i've also tested it with pycharm, so you are telling me that autocomplete just does not work with those packages? Coming from scala/java it is much easier to look into sources and have autocomplete to know library. I'm very new to Python

Comment: @KamilBanaszczyk No idea about pycharm autocompletion. Perhaps it needs source code or even worse — works only with Python modules.